# Is "p if q" the same as "if q then p"?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have the following mathematical statement from my NCERT (Indian) textbook:
"You cannot comprehend geometry if you do not know how to reason deductively."

From what I understand, a statement "p if q" is really the same as p<=q i.e. q=>p because q being true means that p is also true. So, based on this "p if q" is the same as "if q then p".

Applying this logic to the given statement, the statement can be rewritten as:-
"If you do not know how to reason deductively then you cannot comprehend geometry."

However, in my textbook, this statement is interpreted as:-
"If you cannot comprehend geometry then you do not know how to reason deductively."
But this is, I think, based on the idea that "p if q" can be rewritten as "if p then q" - which is wrong in my opinion.

So am I correct, and if so is my reasoning also correct? If I am wrong, then where have I made the mistake? Thanks.

Comment: Class 11 Ex 14.4 Q2) iv.

Comment: Correct: "$p$, if $q$" is "If $q$, then $p$".

Comment: This is really not a math question. It is just how English works. I don't think there is much can be said besides that

Comment: *However, in my textbook, this statement ["You cannot comprehend geometry if you do not know how to reason deductively."] is interpreted as:- "If you cannot comprehend geometry then you do not know how to reason deductively." [...] which is wrong in my opinion.* ... Your opinion is correct: interpreting those two statements as equivalent would be wrong. ... That said, is it possible that the textbook isn't claiming the statements are equivalent but has shifted the discussion to comparing a statement and its "converse"? (The converse of "if $p$ then $q$" is "if $q$ then $p$".)

Comment: Yes, they mean the same thing.

Comment: I agree with @Ray. In modern English the word "if" is often used exchangeably with "if and only if".

Comment: Ray and cr001 are wrong. There is a common abuse of terminology in the use of "if" in definitions, but it is **certainly not the same as** "iff". You are correct, and your reasoning is correct, and your textbook is wrong! What a lousy textbook!